# Finding Iteration Schemes Using Secant Method

Tags: numerical-methods, secant

So im given an equation $f(x) = \frac{1}x - c$ and told to use $f(x) = 0$ and using the secant method to find the iteration scheme for the said equation.

The secant method is: $x_{n+1}$ = $x_n$ - $\dfrac{f(x_n)(x_n - x_{n-1})}{f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})}$

So i proceed to place the $f(x)= \frac{1}x-c$ for every $f(x)$ in the secant equation making sure to keep the $n$ and $n-1$ subscripts, then just try and work it out algebraically? like so?:

$x_n$ - $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{1}{x_n}-c\right)(x_n - x_{n-1})}{\dfrac{1}{x_n}-c-\dfrac{1}{x_{n-1}}-c}$

If so, what is the point of f(x) = 0, will that be plugged in after i have found the iteration? Or must $f(x) = 0$ take the place of $x_n$? I worked a similar problem except it asked to use Newtons Method, but there was no use $f(x) = 0$.

@khonglagica here is how far i made it trying to condense the formula:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgmmq.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any iterative scheme needs some starting points, in this case, is two.

Secondly, did you try to simplify your formula? I think you will get something like $x_{n} - F(x_{n},x_{n-1})$ in a simple form.

Then for some starting point $x_{0} , x_{1}$, compute $x_{n+1}$ by your formula.

Finally, the loop will end when some stopping criteria are met, in this case, I guess it would be $f(x_{n+1})=0$. And that also the place where $f(x) = 0$ are used, which makes sense in Newton method as there is no $f$ in that formula, I guess.

**Update**:
I guess that it should be
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} & = x_{n} - \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{1}{x_{n}} - c \right) \left( x_{n} - x_{n-1} \right)}{\dfrac{1}{x_{n}} - c - \dfrac{1}{x_{n-1}} + c} \\
& = x_{n} - \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{1}{x_{n}} - c \right) \left( x_{n} - x_{n-1} \right)}{\dfrac{x_{n-1} - x_{n}}{x_{n} x_{n-1}}} \\
& = x_{n} + x_{n} x_{n-1} \left( \dfrac{1}{x_{n}} - c \right) \\
& = x_{n} + x_{n-1} - c x_{n} x_{n-1}
\end{align}
here the second equality from below is obtained by multiply $\dfrac{x_{n} x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1} - x_{n}}$ to both denominator and numerator .

Comment: i did try to simplify but I'm getting lost somewhere. I added a picture in the OP.

Comment: P/S: In general:
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} & = \dfrac{x_{n} \left( f(x_{n}) - f(x_{n-1}) \right)}{f \left( x_{n} \right) - f \left( x_{n-1} \right)} - \dfrac{f(x_{n}) \left( x_{n} - x_{n-1} \right)}{f \left( x_{n} \right) - f(x_{n-1})} \\
& = \dfrac{x_{n} f \left( x_{n} \right) - x_{n} f \left( x_{n-1} \right) - \left( x_{n} f \left( x_{n} \right) - x_{n-1} f \left( x_{n} \right) \right)}{f \left( x_{n} \right) - f \left( x_{n-1} \right)} \\
& = \dfrac{x_{n-1} f \left( x_{n} \right) - x_{n} f \left( x_{n-1} \right)}{f \left( x_{n} \right) - f \left( x_{n-1} \right)} .
\end{align}

Comment: sr for the late respond. I was busy for a few day :) using the formula in the update for two given starting point. I hope that you can proceed. 
best :)

Comment: Your last expression is not safe. You will suffer from subtractive cancellation in both your nominator and your denominator as you approach the root. It is better to use the defining expression because it has the from of a good approximation, plus a small correction. It matters less if the correction has a large relative error as long as the correction is small relative to the current approximation.

Comment: many thanks for your advice. does it mean that for any iterative scheme, it would be better to keep the formula at the way it was rather than simplify the expression using the specific form of the problem?

Comment: In general, it is a sound strategy to calculate the improved approximation, by adding a small correction to a good approximation. It matters little if the correction is subject to subtractive cancellation as long as the correction is small relative to the current approximation. 

Note: Tag me or I will not get notification when you comment on your own post. I came here only by coincidence.

Comment: @khongagica you are correct, a classmate and i solved it a few days ago, her answer matches yours. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @UndeadCosmonaut You're welcome. glad that I could help :)